# Implementing Header so its elements (logo images) scaffolds with screen size

Tags: html, css, header

I am trying to make the logos in a header to scaffold (stack downwards) when screen size is decreased. At the moment i get the following:[image]

```
<div id="header_inner">
<div class="logo"><a rel="home" href=""><img src="/logoShort1.png" alt=""></a></div><!-- .logo -->
<div id="header_extras"><div id="header_extras_inner"><div class="header_social"><div class="social_icon awake_dark"><a href="https://twitter.com/"><img src="twitter.png" alt=""></a></div><div class="social_icon awake_dark"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/1?fref=ts"><img src="http://10.10.1.202//facebook.png" alt=""></a></div><div class="social_icon awake_dark"><a href="mailto:info"><img src="http:///email.png" alt=""></a></div></div></div><!-- #header_extras_inner -->
</div>               
<div id="logoMob" class="headerStack"><img src="/logoMobPhone.png"></div>
<div id="logoLand" class="headerStack"><img src="/logoLandline.png"></div>                
 </div>
```

Comment: Please clarify and/or provide a JSFiddle

Comment: Just added an image to try and clarify, is that ok? thanks

Comment: We'll need the css used, so if you could create a JSFiddle, that would help

Comment: I just put this toguether, the idea is that when the window size gets smaller, the forth item goes under the previous and so consecuelty http://jsfiddle.net/secuaz/WtZad/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified your CSS.  It looked like you were trying to do too much.

http://jsfiddle.net/WtZad/1/

**CSS**

```css
#header_inner {
     min-width: 900px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
#header_inner > div {
     float: left;
     margin: 5px;  /* add some space around them */
}
```

Using a set width with `width: 900px;` will create a horizontal scroll bar.  Using `max-width: 990px;` allows it to flex at smaller screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by specifying in CSS `float:left;` and `clear:left;` whilst using Adapt.js you can change load css files dependant on screen size. This way you can make the CSS rules specific for the layout.

Make sure to include the CSS files, JS and the initialisation.

EDIT /*

This is without the JS and a simple media query http://jsfiddle.net/meeb0/mSTrQ/1/

Comment: thanks for your answer!I don't get how to use the clear:left (that prevents an element from being to the left of another element). A jsFiddle would help. Thankyou!

Comment: I have edited the link. It is very simple and without the JS but it works with media queries. Use JS if you are building for non-CSS3 Browsers.

Comment: YOU HAVE TO RESIZE YOUR BROWSER FOR IT TO WORK.. just a side note.. it should turn the element blue. :D